# Show only one value if two values are equal in AMP script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a script setup where I want to show two separate values in the same line of HTML. sometimes the values will be equal. So instead of showing duplicate I need to write a function to display just the second value.

Is there a function that can do this? Can't find any documentation on it.

I've tried this already.

```
%%=IIf(@Value1=@Value2),(%%=v(@Value2=%%)),(%%=v(@Value1)=%% %%=v(@Value2)=%%)=%%
```

Answer (score 2):

It'd be something like this:

`%%=iif(@Value1 == @Value2, @value2, concat(@value1, " ", @value2))=%%`

Or in long form for comparison:

```
%%[

if @value1 == @value2 then

 output(concat(@value2))

else

 output(concat(@value1," ",@value2))

endif

]%%
```

Double-percent notation is only valid outside AMPScript blocks and functions.

Answer (score 0):

%%[

if @value1 == @value2 then

output(concat(@value2))

else

output(concat(@value1," ",@value2))

endif

]%%

Comment: Please also add some words about your solution.